# In react, export variable is always returning false even though we are setting the state to true in UseEffect Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router, use-effect

***Login.jsx***

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
    import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
    import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
    import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
    import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
    import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
    import Link from '@mui/material/Link';
    import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
    import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
    import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
    import LockOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LockOutlined';
    import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
    import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { useFormik } from 'formik';
    import * as yup from 'yup';
    import * as actions from "../actions/Login";
    import { Link as RRDLink, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { useToasts } from "react-toast-notifications";
    import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    
    function Copyright(props) {
        return (
            <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary" align="center" {...props}>
                {'Copyright © '}
                <Link color="inherit" href="https://mui.com/">
                    Rishi
                </Link>{' '}
                {new Date().getFullYear()}
                {'.'}
            </Typography>
        );
    }
    
    const theme = createTheme();
    
    ***let authValue = false;***
    
    const SignInSide = ({ ...props }) => {
    
        //toast msg.
        const { addToast } = useToasts()
    
        let history = useHistory();
    
        const [rememberme_checked, setRememberme_Checked] = useState(false);
    
        ***const [authRishi, setAuthRishi] = useState(false);***
    
        const onSuccess = () => {
            formik.resetForm();
            if (rememberme_checked)
                setRememberme_Checked(!rememberme_checked)        
        };
    
        const formik = useFormik({
            initialValues: {                       
                username: '',
                password: '',
                rememberme: false
            },
            validationSchema: yup.object({                
                username: yup.string().max(20, 'UserName should not exceed 20 characters').required('Please Enter UserName'),
                password: yup.string().required('No password provided.').min(8, 'Password is too short - should be 8 chars minimum.').matches(/[a-zA-Z]/, 'Password can only contain Latin letters.'),
            }),
            onSubmit: values => {
                props.login(values, onSuccess);
            }
        });
    
        const handleCheckbox = () => setRememberme_Checked(!rememberme_checked);
    
        useEffect(() => {
            console.log('login with ' + JSON.stringify(props.loginList))
            props.loginList.map((record, index) => {
                if (record.login_successful) {                
                    ***authValue = setAuthRishi(true)--> Updating the authValue***                               
                    addToast("Login successful", { appearance: 'success', autoDismiss: true })
                    history.push('/Home')
                    record.login_successful = false;
                }
                else {               
                    addToast("Login Failed. Please try again with valid credentials", { appearance: 'error', autoDismiss: true })     
                       setAuthRishi(false)          
                }
            })
        }, [props.loginList])
    
        return (
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <Grid container component="main" sx={{ height: '100vh' }}>
                    <CssBaseline />
                    <Grid
                        item
                        xs={false}
                        sm={4}
                        md={7}
                        sx={{
                            backgroundImage: 'url(https://source.unsplash.com/random)',
                            backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
                            backgroundColor: (t) =>
                                t.palette.mode === 'light' ? t.palette.grey[50] : t.palette.grey[900],
                            backgroundSize: 'cover',
                            backgroundPosition: 'center',
                        }}
                    />
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={8} md={5} component={Paper} elevation={6} square>
                        <Box
                            sx={{
                                my: 8,
                                mx: 4,
                                display: 'flex',
                                flexDirection: 'column',
                                alignItems: 'center',
                            }}
                        >
                            <Avatar sx={{ m: 1, bgcolor: 'secondary.main' }}>
                                <LockOutlinedIcon />
                            </Avatar>
                            <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                                Sign in
                            </Typography>
                            <Box component="form" onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit} sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                                <TextField
                                    margin="normal"
                                    required
                                    fullWidth
                                    id="username"
                                    label="User Name"
                                    name="username"
                                    autoComplete="username"
                                    
                                    {...formik.getFieldProps("username")}
                                />
                                {formik.touched.username && formik.errors.username ?
                                    <span style={{ color: 'red' }}>{formik.errors.username}</span> : null}
                                <TextField
                                    margin="normal"
                                    required
                                    fullWidth
                                    name="password"
                                    label="Password"
                                    type="password"
                                    id="password"
                                    autoComplete="current-password"
                                    {...formik.getFieldProps("password")}
                                />
                                {formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password ?
                                    <span style={{ color: 'red' }}>{formik.errors.password}</span> : null}
                                <FormControlLabel                                
                                    control={<Checkbox name="rememberme" color="primary" onClick={handleCheckbox} checked={rememberme_checked} value={formik.values.rememberme}
                                        onChange={formik.handleChange} />}
                                    label="Remember me"
                                />
                                <Button
                                    type="submit"
                                    fullWidth
                                    variant="contained"
                                    sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
                                >
                                    Sign In
                                </Button>
                                <Grid container>
                                    <Grid item xs>
                                        <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                                            Forgot password?
                                        </Link>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Grid item>                                                                            
                                            <RRDLink to="/Learning">
                                                Don't have an account? Sign Up
                                            </RRDLink>                                                                                                                                         
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                                <Copyright sx={{ mt: 5 }} />
                            </Box>
                        </Box>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ThemeProvider>
        );
    }
    
    ***export const authRishi = authValue;***
    
    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        loginList: state.login.login
    })
    
    const mapActionToProps = {
        login: actions.post
    }
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionToProps)(SignInSide);
```

So, from login.jsx I want to export the authRishi value which is of bool data type. In the useEffect hook I will get the server response in this format **{login_successful: true, email: rishi@gmail.com}**. And based on the login_successful value I will be setting up the authRishi value and I will be redirecting either to home or NotAuthorized page. Currently my authRishi value is always coming as false(Even though I have update setAuthRishi state to true) and its been redirected to NotAuthorized page. Please help me to export the updated authRishi value to app.js component. Below is the App.js component

```
***App.js***


import React from 'react';
import Learning from './components/Learning';
import Login, { authRishi } from './components/Login';
import Home from "./components/HomePage";
import NotAuthorized from "./components/URLPage";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>                          
                <div className="container px-3 mx-auto">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/Learning" component={Learning} />                        
                        <Route
                            exact
                            path='/Home'
                            render={() => authRishi ? (<Home />) : (<NotAuthorized/>)} />
                        <Route path="/" component={Login} />
                    </Switch>                  
                </div>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
   
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You `export const authRishi = authValue;` and only set `authValue` to be false with `let authValue = false;` so OFC `authRishi` will ***always*** be false. Unrestricted "globals" are anti-pattern in React and mutating their values doesn't trigger rerenders. Since you area already using Redux why not move the local `authRishi` state of `SignInSide` into your Redux store and access that in `App`? This would be the correct React way.

Comment: Thanks, @DrewReese will try the same.